# IIS 7.5 asp.net application not running

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

My asp.net MVC application not working in IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, but it's  working fine in IIS 8 with Windows 10.

In my live server I am facing the same. In my server I have Windows 2012 r2
[image: iis error image]

I was creating a demo application, but faced the same issue.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Can you share the full screen? it looks like that URL is not getting to .NET

Comment: Have you tried to enable the folder to display it with iis? If you did not enable the iis_iusrs user permissions, the error seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 4 was not registered in IIS. had to run the following command in the command line/run

32bit (x86) Windows:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

64bit (x64) Windows:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir